# Lync 2013 SDK - get Generic COM Exception at the time of calling LyncClient.GetClient()

Tags: lync-2013, lync-client-sdk, skype-for-business

On my development machine Lync 2013 client and Skype for Business both applications are installed. When attempting to call LyncClient.GetClient() compiled using the Lync 2013 SDK against Skype for Business the following exception is raised.
***Generic COM Exception. Code is 0x80080005.***

If I uninstalled the Lync 2013 client then it works perfectly.

For the Lync 2013 client development I have also used Lync 2013 SDK at that time I didn't get any exception.

Can anyone tell me that why this exception is raised when both applications are installed?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "Skype for Business"?

AFAIK the clients can't be installed at the same time (which is most likely the reason for problems I think).  So you can only have one client installed at any one time.

Also the clients are confusing as well.

There are:

- Lync Basic Client (with windows updated to Skype for Business 2015 UI)
- Lync (full) Client as part of Office Professional Plus 2013 (with windows updated to Skype for Business 2015 UI)
- Skype for Business Standalone (Office 2016 post install)

Comment: Skype for Business Standalone (Office 2016 post install)